# Opencv native location set up for java-eclipse linux based

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to setup a java based opencv program to run on raspberry-pi.I installed opencv-2.4.8 on my raspberry-pi. I also installed eclipse to set up opencv.The problem is i am not able to link native libraries for my opencv-2.4.8 jar file in eclipse.

[image: checked opencv on pi]

Eclipse is running fine with raspberry-pi and i am able to compile and run simple java programs.From where to link the native library for opencv2.4.8 jar file.

[image]
 I checked my opencv folder and it is having the following structure.

MY OpenCV Folder
[image: My opencv folder]

Opencv release folder
[image: Opencv release folder]

Found the following opencv .so files in **usr/local/lib** folder of my pi. Is this is what i should link to my native library. But there are many .so files also.
[image]

The output console with the error is as follows. sorry the screenshot skipped unsatisfied link error..
[image]

Comment: Could you post the exact error you are getting as a result of not being able to link the native files? What does it say when you try to run your program?

Comment: I am getting an unsatisfied link error.

Comment: It is to do with the linking the native class.But how to do it is my issue?Is opencv installation is fine.. How to link it??

Comment: In windows we actually link build/java/x86/opencvjava248.dll to the native library path of opencv-2.4.8 jar file.
Since this is now linux,it is not possible to add the dll file.

Comment: Check the output of `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`, see if /usr/local/lib is there. If it isn't, add it using `System.setProperty()`. Let me know if that fixes anything.

Comment: Usually, you link the lib you are using. OpenCV has many libraries. For example, if you are only using opencv2/core, opencv2/highgui and opencv2/imgproc in your code, then you only need to link those three libraries. In Makefile, it's -lopencv_core, -lopencv_highgui, -lopencv_imgproc.
Make sure your library path include /usr/local/lib/ and your include path has /usr/local/include/opencv2

Comment: @DXM Tried this and no difference.. I have added the console error (see edit above)

Comment: @slaveCoder, When I was working on openCV I also got the same error. After that I added all the library of ffmpeg,openCV and javaCv and then removed one by one. Now its working fine. I know this not a solution but still...

Comment: @krispy No change mate.. still issue persists..

Comment: @Anukuttan What does your java.library.path actually print out?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error which come up like this. I have an application that I have to run. I build and install opencv and try to run but I see that error like you. For solving this issue I replace old `opencv_*jar` with built one in opencv directory. You have to use jar file that you have just built.

> ..../opencv/build/bin/opencv-2410.jar

I thing old jar looks for different native path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I set my Native Lib Location to {OpenCV directory}/{Build directory}/lib and things worked fine.